When is E[Xi*ui]=0 violated, given that the residuals are by construction of the model uncorrelated with the predictors?
To begin: I am aware that the concepts of the "error term" and "residual" two distinct ones. Yet, I have difficulties understanding their implications for (multiple) linear regression and linear projection models.
In my class we introduced a linear projection model for any PRF (not necessary linear), where one of the key concepts is orthogonality:
E[Xi*ui)=0 (where 0 is a (k+1)*1-vector).
In case of a constant in the model Xi and ui would be uncorrelated. Assuming that ui here is the error term, I dont understand how that property (of no correlation) can be true if the error term and the predictors are in any way correlated.

I dont understand how E[Xi * ui] can be identified. If Xi and ui are correlated, then Xi and the residuals would still be uncorrelated by construction and I assume that we would use the residuals to identify E[Xi * ui] since we cannot observe ui.

If Xi and ui are correlated does that imply that E[Xi *ui) does not equal zero?

When is E[Xi * ui]= 0 violated? and how can we identify any violiation?


I hope my questions even make sense, thank you in advance :)


Why do you think we want to identify (I assume you mean "estimate") $\mathrm{E}x_iu_i$?  2. No, the product of two correlated variables can still have an expected value of zero.   (The product of two zero-mean correlated variables, on the other hand, cannot have an expected value of zero.) 3. Model misspecification is the usual cause of this violation, and identification - in the non-statistical usage - is, I would expect, usually done by a domain expert looking at your model and saying "no, that's wrong, you left (this) out" or some such.

